# Superscript in matplotlib of 2- or more digits numbers with variable call

Tags: python, plot, superscript

I am trying to create a plot with a legend containing a reaction where I need to use superscripts inside a loop. My variable `ho_isots = [159,160,161,162,163,164]` and I would like to have the trends labeled as follow: <sup>nat</sup>Dy(p,x)<sup>161</sup>Ho, for example, instead I get <sup>nat</sup>Dy(p,x)<sup>1</sup>61Ho.

Any suggestion? Thank you in advance.

This is the loop:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for isot,th_cs in zip(ho_isots,th_cs_holmium):
    ax.plot(ep_thcs,th_cs,linewidth=2,label=f'$^{{nat}}$Dy(p,x)$^{isot}$Ho')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwkwZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/),

> Expressions appear within curly braces '{' and '}'. While scanning
> the string for expressions, any doubled braces '{{' or '}}' inside
> literal portions of an f-string are replaced by the corresponding
> single brace.

So, your f-string label after processing looks like `'$^{nat}$Dy(p,x)$^159$Ho'` (notice how double braces are replaced by a single one, and `{isot}` got replaced with the actual value). This string gets  indeed translated by Matplotlib as <sup>nat</sup>Dy(p,x)<sup>1</sup>61Ho. To overcome this, you have to put the `isot` value in the curly braces, making it triple: `f'$^{{nat}}$Dy(p,x)$^{{{isot}}}$Ho'`